# Python MySql : Where to put the MySql queries (design choice)?

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm writing a Python application that interacts with a MySql database. The basic way to do this is to connect to the database and execute the queries using the database's cursor object. Should I hardcode each query in the python code, or should I put each query in a stored procedure ? Which is the better design choice (keeping security and elegance in mind) ? Note that many of the queries are single-liners (select queries).

Comment: Is it a Mysql cursor?

Comment: Is the server-side cursor necessary? Usually they perform like crap cuz you are not harnessing the power of sql engines. Other times cursors seem the only route but as a last resort